# Pushing my repository to heroku fails

Tags: java, git, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

Im building an app in play 2.0, and when I run the app locally with `play run` it runs fine but when I try to upload to heroku with `git push heroku master` it starts uploading fine but after a while it always ends with these errors:

```
 [info] Compiling 10 Scala sources and 6 Java sources to /tmp/build_26zvdeyfp5qfp/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
       [error] error while loading MapStream, class file '/tmp/build_26zvdeyfp5qfp/.jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/MapStream.class)' is broken
       [error] (bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 43)
       [error] one error found
       [error] {file:/tmp/build_26zvdeyfp5qfp/}Workshop0182Host/compile:compile: Compilation failed
       [error] Total time: 20 s, completed Nov 17, 2012 11:08:23 AM
 !     Failed to build app with sbt
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.0 - java app

To git@heroku.com:dry-thicket-4545.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:dry-thicket-4545.git'
```

I made sure that my heroku-toolbelt is up-to-date, tried to completely reinitialise git and created a new heroku app. But none of that helped me any further

Comment: What JDK version are you using a locally ?

Comment: You should fine a support request with Heroku.

Comment: @nico_ekito, 1.7 I think, does that really matter? But I made sure that I configured heroku to the same version.

Comment: @James Ward, is this error so exotic then? :p Well I guess I'll do that then. Also completely unrelated, but your play 2.0 tutorial on your blog really helped me so thanks for that.

Comment: This is definitely an exotic error.  Seems like maybe a corruption in their JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently using JDK 1.8 in heroku gives this problem.

Comment: Were you setting 1.8 in `system.properties`? Also, were you using 1.8 locally?