# Maven: package does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, heroku

I was developing an application like ordinary Java Web application, but because I want to deploy it to Heroku, I needed it to become Maven project, so I created an empty Maven project with Eclipse and copied all of libraries I was using and all of my source code.

When I do `mvn compile` on my local machine, it goes well, but app isn't really working.

When I do `git push heroku master` I get error like

```
package com.mysite.java.classes does not exist
```

Locally I have `maven-compiler-plugin` ver 3.1 and source and target set to 1.7, although I'm using 1.8 jdk. I changed it to 1.7 since I saw here [Pushing my repository to heroku fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430032/pushing-my-repository-to-heroku-fails) that it has issues with Heroku.

Here is a project structure

[image]

I'm not really experienced with Maven, so I hope somebody can help. I guess imports aren't working as intended because I get whole list of errors like this

```
symbol:   class Connection
location: class com.vukstankovic.professionalorientation.Personalities
[ERROR] /tmp/build_0bc5a80c-dc14-4126-b15b-69390f18dc9f/src/main/java/com/vukstankovic/professionalorientation/Personalities.java:[48,19] cannot find symbol
```

Class `Connection` in this example is mysql class from `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection`

Comment: Can you provide the project's structure?

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Comment: Can you add the pom.xml, please? I would like the scope for mysql connector dependency.